# How does NUGET package management works on Microsoft MAUI?

Tags: xamarin, maui

There are significant differences compared to Xamarin and I couldn't find docs or even a discussion about the matter, and I am interested in knowing. It was pretty straight forward in Xamarin. If I wanted a nuget package for the android project and not the whole solution I could do that, but now it's just one project.

Comment: It should be similar to [Multi-targetting for nuget - framework versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/supporting-multiple-target-frameworks). Though I'm not sure the exact details to target `.net6-android`. You could ask this by opening an issue at github maui. If you do, please add a link here to that issue, so people can find it from here.

Comment: What specifically do you want to know about? Question is very broad right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could specify the **name** and **version** of the package in `.csproj`  file  and set the certain platform with property `Condition` .

#### For example

1. If you just want to add the package to single platform

```java
<ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1"  Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-ios'" />
</ItemGroup>
```

2. If you want to add the package to multiple platforms

```java
<ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1"  Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-ios' or '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net6.0-android'" />
</ItemGroup>
```

---

PS : Firstly make sure the package support `net6.0` and `net6.0 - xx` before you add the package .